# Problem overriding some Bulma Sass variables

Tags: sass, bulma

I am trying to customize Bulma by overriding some Sass variables.

In my **app.scss** file I import the files using the following order:

```
@import 'node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/initial-variables';
@import 'node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/functions';
@import 'bulma_overrides';
@import 'node_modules/bulma/bulma';
```

The file **bulma_overrides.scss** includes the following:

```
$footer-padding: 3rem 1.5rem 3rem;
$footer-background-color: whitesmoke;
```

My goal was to make the footer a little bit thinner, and I tried to achieve this by changing the padding from **3rem 1.5rem 6rem** to **3rem 1.5rem 3rem**. At the same time I am changing the backgroud color to whitesmoke.

After running and successfully building:

```
npm run watch
```

I reload the page.

Result:

**The background color of the footer changes just fine but the padding does not.**

At first, I thought that maybe this is not something we can customize, but the official documentation says that we can:

https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/footer/

Any ideas why? By the way, I faced the same issue with another variable in a previous project, and I can't understand what is going on.

PS1: i am using Laravel 5.7 for this project. No changes are done in **webpack.mix.js**

PS2: i tried multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge[lol]) but no luck.

Comment: show your folder structure of bulma

Comment: The folder structure inside node_modules or inside Laravel's resources?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have exactly the same behaviour

Comment: @anorakgirl unfortunately no. I thought to build my backend first and then start worrying about the front-end details. But if I have some news I will surely update my question.

Comment: Yea this is annoying to say the least, im thinking of just making a second navbar at the bottom and make it a footer

Comment: Try moving the `bulma_overrides` import to the top

Answer (score 1):

Your bulma import is already importing "sass/utilities/_all", so this **app.scss** worked for me just fine:

```
// Bulma Overrides
@import 'bulma_overrides';

// Bulma
@import '~bulma/bulma';
```