# Overriding Bulma initial variables in all.sass file?

Tags: css, sass, bulma

I am trying to override default behavior in Bulma. I have found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60901806/cant-overwrite-bulma-navbar-color) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53882642/problem-overriding-some-bulma-sass-variables) but seemingly no answer. My .sass file looks like [this](https://github.com/netlify-templates/gatsby-starter-netlify-cms/blob/master/src/components/all.sass). I want to change the color assigned to h2, but I can't figure out how to overwrite the default behavior.  Here is what I have tried adding in the middle of the .sass file:

```
.content h2
  color: $primary
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this issue is that your are defining the `.content .h2` part *before* importing.

If you haven't yet, try this:

```css
@import "~bulma"

.content h2
   color: $primary
```